# What does "git checkout -" do?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-checkout

I saw a weird type of git checkout command.

```
git checkout -
```

What does `-` do here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the same as doing `cd -`. So you go back to the last branch. These three sequences do the same, if you start from *master*:

```
# Way 1
git checkout mybranch
git checkout master

# Way 2 (same result)
git checkout mybranch
git checkout -

# Way 3 (same result)
git checkout mybranch
git checkout @{-1}
```

As [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) mentioned, you can go back to the nth previously checked out branch by using `@{-N}`

Comment: That's cool. Been using *nix for a decade and never saw `cd -` before

Comment: Worth noting that `-` is a shortcut for `@{-1}`, where `@{-N}` refers to the nth previous checked-out branch.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that @chepner, will add it to the answer, thx!

Answer (score 0):

It switches back to the branch you were on previously. If you run it again, you’re toggled back to the first branch. A useful comparison is `cd -`, which as you may know takes you back to your most recent directory.

[Have a look in this source](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/git-checkout-and-see)

Answer (score 0):

It does a checkout out to the last branch (I think).

```
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$ git branch mybranch
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$ ls
hello.py
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$ git checkout mybranch
Switched to branch 'mybranch'
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$ ls
hello.py
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$ git checkout -
Switched to branch 'master'
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$
```

You can view below to see my own idiocy.

<s>I don't think it does anything.</s>

```
Keenens-MacBook:sentiment-rnn keenencates$ cd testdir/
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$ ls
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/keenencates/Documents/Udacity/DLND/master_projects/sentiment-rnn/testdir/.git/
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$ vim hello.py
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$ ls
hello.py
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$ git add .
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$ git commit
[master (root-commit) 2ffa8de] init
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 hello.py
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$ ls
hello.py
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$ git checkout -
error: pathspec '-' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Keenens-MacBook:testdir keenencates$
```